# Start of Day from one timezone to GMT

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment-timezone library to build a UI that needs to be relative to a variety of timezones.

I am taking an input of a timezone, i.e "America/Chicago" and need to get the start of day in GMT.

For instance, if today is March 27th at 9am Chicago time (2pm GMT), I need to get the date in epoch seconds for March 27th, 00:00 AM.

I'm using the `moment.tz("America/Chicago").startOf('day')` but I keep getting `Tue Mar 27 2018 01:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` . Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// This part you are already doing correctly.
// You get back a Moment object representing the start of the current day in Chicago:

var m = moment.tz("America/Chicago").startOf('day');
```

> I need to get the date in epoch seconds

```
// Ok, so simply now get the associated Unix Time
var timestamp = m.unix();
```

Also note that the correct terminology is "Unix Time", not "epoch seconds".
See my blog post: ["Please don't call it Epoch Time"](https://codeofmatt.com/2017/10/05/please-dont-call-it-epoch-time/).

> ... but I keep getting `Tue Mar 27 2018 01:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

You are probably either looking at `_d` or a `Date` object, or rather the string representation of one.  Don't. See [this Moment.js documentation](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) for details.

Per your comment:

> I need to take the current time in a specific timezone. I then need to convert that time to the corresponding day in GMT. Finally I need to get the midnight epoch timestamp of that GMT day.

That's a little different then you originally asked, but it would be like this:

```
var timestamp = moment.utc().startOf('day').unix();
```

Note that there's no purpose in involving another time zone for this operation.  Logically, when asking for "Now in time zone A converted to time zone B", it's the same as asking for "Now in time zone B".  In other words, you would get the same value even when the time zone was present:

```
var timestamp = moment.tz('America/Chicago').utc().startOf('day').unix();
```

So you're better off just leaving the time zone out.

Comment: Ah I was so close! Thank you!