# Moment startOf date starts at 8AM

Tags: momentjs

I noticed this while trying to do a compare.

```
const elevenMthsAgoS = moment().subtract(11, "months").startOf("date");
```

Returns the date eleven months ago but at 8AM? How can I get it to 000 the time.
Should I do end of date on day before? Or is there a better way?

Comment: this answer might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519725/start-of-day-from-one-timezone-to-gmt

Answer (score 0):

you use moment or moment-timezone?

I run follow lines now maybe help you :

```
var moment = require("moment");
var momentTimezone = require("moment-timezone");

const elevenMthsAgoS = moment().subtract(11, "months").startOf("date");

console.log(elevenMthsAgoS);           // Moment<2020-02-25T00:00:00+03:30>
console.log(elevenMthsAgoS.format());  // 2020-02-25T00:00:00+03:30


var jun = momentTimezone("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
var dec = momentTimezone("2014-12-01T12:00:00Z");

console.log(jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z'));  // 5am PDT
console.log(dec.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z'));  // 4am PST
```